# only write predefined text in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do in textbox only add predefined text.

```html
<input type="text" class="mytxt" onkeyup="return SplitChar(this.id);">
<script>
  function SplitChar(txt) {
    var mainval = document.getElementById(txt).value;
    var Data = "hello".split('');
    var Datas = mainval.split('');
    var charLen = mainval;
    if (Datas[mainval.length - 1] == Data[charLen.length - 1]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(txt).value = mainval.substr(0, mainval.length - 1);
      alert("Please write as specified example");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

in this text box only written "helloo" nothing else 
 i want to check on keyup event. and whith out use event function

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: What should occur if user input is not exactly "helloo"?

Comment: @shrddhapatel Can you include code at text of Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i want to do like if user enter 'h' than okk than after 'e' than 'l' not allow other latter

Comment: @shrddhapatel if someone requests you for additional information, please add this information in question. Comments can be hidden if many comments are there. Also, comment section is for discussion and not for vital information

Comment: yes @guest271314

Comment: @shrddhapatel Your code seems to work fine. You are just missing `id` on HTML.

Comment: Note, the `<input> ` element does not have `id` set though `this.id` is passed to `SplitChar` at `onkeyup` event attribute.

Comment: i done that part @guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

Remove `this.id` in `onkeyup="return SplitChar(this.id);"` because you aready accessing in JS as `var mainval`and add `id` to `input` because you accessing its value based on `id`

```js
 function SplitChar() {
    var mainval = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var Data = "hello".split('');
    var Datas = mainval.split('');
    var charLen = mainval;
    if (Datas[mainval.length - 1] == Data[charLen.length - 1]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('txt').value = mainval.substr(0, mainval.length - 1);
      alert("Please write as specified example");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text"  class="mytxt" id="txt" onkeyup="return SplitChar();">
```

Comment: What was the issue? What have you changed? Why does it solve the issue? Please add explanation to your answer. You are answering for readers and not just OP

Comment: thank u @Znaneswar. but I also do when the whole word is written means when hello word is written at last time alert box popup completed